# MySQL query - Join data based on two factors, then customise the way the data is sorted based on values

Tags: sql, mysql

firstly I'm new to querying multiple tables so I apologise if this is a bit of a stupid question, but we all have to start somewhere!

I've made a picture which should make this easier to understand:

http://www.mediumsliced.co.uk/temp/mysqlhelp.jpg

My first table **wp_user** has several columns - I want the values from 3 columns which are ID user_email and user_nicename.
My second table **wp_usermeta** has 3 columns which stores meta data for the users. These columns are user_id, meta_key and meta_value. The user_id values in this table always correspond to the matching ID values in **wp_user** (see picture).

I would like to join data from the meta_key fields along with it's meta_value. So far I have this:

```
SELECT wp_users.ID, wp_users.user_login, wp_users.user_nicename, wp_users.user_email,
       wp_usermeta.user_id, wp_usermeta.meta_key, wp_usermeta.meta_value
FROM wp_users, wp_usermeta
WHERE (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id);
```

This displays all the info I need however the issue I have is that I actually want to display the data from meta_key as individual columns and the meta_value for that meta key in the correct row for that user based on their ID. I also need to exclude any users which do not have their wp_user_level as 0. (Again hopefully this is clearer on my picture I provided)

Obviously I have a lot to learn when it comes to MySql but if anyone could guide me to the end result I'd be really grateful, even more so if you could explain the query so that I can learn from it as opposed to just copy and paste it in place.

Thanks a lot if you need more information or need me to clarify anything then feel free to ask!

Craig

Comment: EAV tables are an extremely poor design and very hard to effectively query and poor performers. Suggest you do the work to define what columns you need and redisgn to normalized tabales.

Comment: @HLGEM, I think he has to live with it -> http://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_usermeta

Comment: @Unreason - Bonus feature: there does not appear to be anything in the database that prevents having two meta rows for the same user_id with the same meta_key but different values.

Comment: Btw, +1 for showing us a diagram and the actual output desired.

Answer (score 3):

```
Select wp_users.ID
    , wp_users.user_login
    , wp_users.user_email
    , wp_users.user_nicename
    , Min( Case When wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'first_name' Then wp_usermeta.meta_value End ) As first_name
    , Min( Case When wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'last_name' Then wp_usermeta.meta_value End ) As last_name
    , Min( Case When wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'address' Then wp_usermeta.meta_value End ) As address
    , Min( Case When wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'dob' Then wp_usermeta.meta_value End ) As dob
From wp_user
    Join wp_usermeta
        On wp_usermeta.user_id = wp_user.ID
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From wp_usermeta As Meta1
                Where Meta1.user_id = wp_user.id
                    And Meta1.meta_key = 'wp_user_level' 
                    And Meta1.meta_value = '0' 
                )
        And wp_usermeta.meta_key In('first_name','last_name','address','dob')                   
Group By wp_users.ID
    , wp_users.user_login
    , wp_users.user_email
    , wp_users.user_nicename
```

First, as others have mentioned, one of the reasons that this query is so cumbersome to write is that you are having to use an EAV structure. The concept of a "meta" table is really an anathema to relational design. Second, in order to get information out of an EAV, you have to create what is called a crosstab query where you build the columns you want in your query. In general, relational databases are not designed for on-the-fly column generation such as I'm doing in my solution and is required for EAVs.

Comment: +1 for different approach, it would be nice if OP did a performance comparison

Comment: `+1`, I'd expect that to perform better than the multiple-outer-join solution, but performance would have to be tested.

Comment: @Peter Lang, @Unreason - Tough to say if it would perform better. I would guess that it depends on how many outer joins would be necessary and how much data existed in the table. TBH, the only catch with the outer join approach is that it relies on user_id+meta_key being unique which does not appear to be enforced. If you got two identical meta_key values for the same user_id, an outer join would give you a duplicate row in the output. Of course, that said, my solution would arbitrary choose the "min" value of the two.

Comment: Thanks also Thomas I'll be looking at both yours and Unreason's code doing a bit of learning then implementing. Really appreciate everyone's help, it's the first time i've used this website and I'm shocked at the speed, quality and level of answers to such questions! You're all stars!

Comment: ).. ah, I was waiting to catch you on the 'arbitrary' (i.e. hiding problems vs. breaking) but you mentioned it :)

Answer (score 2):

Continuing your example

```
SELECT 
    wp_users.ID, 
    wp_users.user_login, 
    wp_users.user_nicename, 
    wp_users.user_email, 
    wp_usermeta.user_id, 
    wp_usermeta.meta_key, 
    wp_usermeta.meta_value 
FROM 
    wp_users, wp_usermeta 
WHERE 
   (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id) AND (wp_usermeta.wp_user_level = 0);
```

should give you what you need.
Notes:

- format your SQL
- instead of a WHERE condition on id=user_id, it could have been a join

like this:

```
SELECT 
    ...
FROM 
    wp_users INNER JOIN
    wp_usermeta ON wp_users.id = wp_usermeta.user_id
WHERE
    wp_usermeta.wp_user_level = 0
```

EDIT: As for the meta data and meta properties you have to join the meta_table as many times as there will be properties

so for example to get

```
SELECT 
    wp_users.ID, 
    wp_users.user_login, 
    wp_users.user_nicename, 
    wp_users.user_email, 
    m1.meta_value as first_name
    m2.meta_value as last_name
    m3.meta_value as address
    m4.meta_value as dob
FROM 
    wp_users 
    INNER JOIN wp_usermeta m ON wp_users.id = m.user_id AND m.meta_key = "wp_user_level" AND m.meta_value = 0
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta m1 ON wp_users.id = m1.user_id AND m1.meta_key = "first_name"
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta m2 ON wp_users.id = m2.user_id AND m1.meta_key = "last_name"
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta m3 ON wp_users.id = m3.user_id AND m1.meta_key = "address"
    LEFT JOIN wp_usermeta m4 ON wp_users.id = m4.user_id AND m1.meta_key = "dob"
```

As you can see the [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model#Structure_of_an_EAV_table) approach, although it allows great reuse of UI elements, does not do wonders for the actual structure of the database (slower and more complex queries, limited integrity validation and at the end code that operates on such structures is more complex).

If possible maybe the right approach is to deal with 'aggregation' on the application level.

Comment: Thank you very much for your speedy answer Unreason, however the issue is that wp_user_level is actually a value and not already its own existing column. wp_user_level is a value within the column wp_usermeta.meta_key so I need to firstly target that value and the corresponding value in wp_usermeta.meta_vale (which are just values not columns). So I get an unknown column error with the code you provided. If you see where wp_user_level is in the picture I provided that might make more sense, sorry for the poor formatting too!

Comment: @Craig, I see about the wp_user_level... editing... the second one should give you what you need and I'll fix it in the first query, too.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks again for your fast replies, I'll give this a try once I make sure I understand what's going on here. You guys are making me realise that I can't just get by knowing the basics in this field! The speed at which you solve these sort of things is just unreal!!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that all keys exist in `wp_usermeta`, you can simply join the table several times. Use `Left Join` in case values might be missing.

```
Select
  u.ID,
  u.user_login,
  u.user_nicename,
  u.user_email,
  m_first_name.meta_value As first_name,
  m_last_name.meta_value  As last_name,
  m_address.meta_value    As address,
  m_dob.meta_value        As dob
From wp_users u
Join wp_usermeta m_first_name On (     m_first_name.user_id = u.id
                                   And m_first_name.meta_key  = 'first_name' )
Join wp_usermeta m_last_name  On (     m_last_name.user_id    = u.id
                                   And m_last_name.meta_key   = 'last_name' )
Join wp_usermeta m_address    On (     m_address.user_id      = u.id
                                   And m_address.meta_key     = 'address' )
Join wp_usermeta m_dob        On (     m_dob.user_id          = u.id
                                   And m_dob.meta_key         = 'dob' )
Join wp_usermeta m_user_level On (     m_user_level.user_id   = u.id
                                   And m_user_level .meta_key = 'm_user_level' )
Where m_user_level.meta_value = '0';
```

Comment: need to be left joins if querying an EAV table where you do not know in advance if the value wll exist.

Comment: @HLGEM: Right, I tried to cover that in the text before the query.

Comment: +1, I edited the last version in my answer - basically the same. Another approach would be to use `id IN (SELECT user_id FROM wp_usermeta WHERE meta_key = "wp_user_level" AND meta_value = '0')`.
Also there are some copy/paste artefacts on keys of last joined table in your query - m_dob?.meta_key = 'm?_user_level'

Comment: @Unreason: Thanks for pointing out the copy/paste mistake, fixed that. `+1` for your updated answer too.

Comment: Cheers also, and thank you for fixing my poorly formatted code! I really appreciate all the help you guys have provided and i'm sure i'll have something more challenging for you next time :P

Answer (score 0):

YOu will have to left join to the meta table separately for each value you want to pull out of it. This is one fo the reasons why EAV tables are an anti-pattern for relational databases.

Also please learn to do explicit joins. Implicit joins will get you in trouble as they can result in accidental cross joins when things get complex (and you will only be writing complex queries with a design this poor.) Also they are bad when you need to to left joins (as you will need to do inthis bad design as you don;t know if the person has a vlue for each attriubute.

Comment: I appreciate that this method of getting the data isn't the best at all, in fact it's terrible. The only thing is that there are many dependencies on keeping all the data as it is now. Because this is an addition to the i'm using the data and it wasn't thought of from stage one i realise it needs some looking at. This is a query which will be rarely used so server load compared to the potential time in rebuilding plugins and migrating data says that this is the best option for me. Thank you very much for your comments you've led me to do some serious coffee fuelled reading!!