# Help with PHP MYSQL Select Statment

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to grasp how I can select records when the records of one user span multiple rows.

Here is the schema of the table.

```
user_id  key          value
------------------------------------------
1        text         this is sample text
1        text_status  0
2        text         this is sample text
2        text_status  1
```

from the above table/row you can see that each user has info that has multiple rows.  So in this case how do I select say "All the IDs, text value where text_status  is "1"?

And to complicate it 1 step further, I need the email address of these accounts which is on another table.  How can I write 1 select statement to pull in the email address as well?  I know there is a JOIN statement for this but it's a bit complicated for me especially I can't even figure out the first part.

*Added Note* I must state that this table schema is a Wordpress default table wp_usermeta..

Comment: Why isn't `text_status` another field in this table?

Comment: Can you explain why `WHERE key = 'text_status' AND value = '1'` won't work?

Comment: `key` and `value` looks wrong. You've designed your table in a way that contravenes the way Database Management Systems are designed to work, which is leading to your problem. Read about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Comment: @OMGPonies: He wants the `value` in the row where `key = "text"`, for the `user_id` for whom a row exists with `key = "text_status"` and `value="1"`. He designed the database wrong.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Text_status isn't a column for the same reason text isn't - the OPs setup supports multiple key/value pairs without impacting columns.  There is a finite limit on the number of columns a table will support.  Depending on need, the table is setup better than you think.

Comment: @OMGPonies: No, it represents a design flaw more than you think. In the past we've gone the same route for "flexibility", or because we thought we couldn't plan ahead of time. We were wrong, and it cost us gravely when it came to actually using the damned thing. If you need extensibility, add tables: never, _never_ treat one table in this way.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: Absolutes are dangerous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT t1.*
      FROM tbl t2
INNER JOIN tbl t1 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id
                 AND t1.key = 'text'
     WHERE t2.key = 'text_status'
       AND t2.value = '1'
```

Comment: +1: Might need a DISTINCT for sake of using a JOIN - IN/EXISTS wouldn't require DISTINCT

Comment: ... `AND t1.key = 'text'`, or you get all rows for matching `user_id`s.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: cannot get, `distinct` for what?

Comment: @zerkms: No problem. Except you put it in the wrong place. It should be the last line.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: no it shouldn't. And to be clear before execution mysql optimizer will join all the conditions (from where as well as from ON for inner join) into one line. So doesn't matter where to put it - it will not change execution plan ;-) Btw, I think the place I put it is more correct.

Comment: @zerkms: Actually yes you're right, the condition is fine where it is. I forgot `ON` syntax for a second (am more used to `USING` for `JOIN`s). Sorry.

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: yup. But as I said it was put there just for readability purposes. If we move that condition to the `WHERE` it will not change anything for mysql query optimizer (and execution plan builder).

Comment: @zerkms: I agree. I also agree that it makes the most sense where it is now.

Comment: In an INNER JOIN, criteria doesn't matter - WHERE or ON clause, it makes no difference.  That wouldn't be the case with an OUTER JOIN though.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: that is what exactly I tried to say. Probably language issues :-S

Comment: Sorry, [TLDR](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=tldr).  I mentioned the DISTINCT thing cuz if there's more than one relation in the JOIN - might not be in this data example, but you know how reliable question criteria can be :)

Comment: @zerkms - thanks for putting up the code.  But I am confused on your terminalogy.  does t1 mean table 1?  Then what does tbl t2 mean?  If it means table 2, then why not just put t2 instead of tbl t2?  Another words I am confused if I am suppose to add something where you state tbl and where you don't.  Thanks..

Comment: @Rick: In my query I joined the table `tbl` to itself. `t1` and `t2` are just an aliases to the same table so we can refer to it.

Comment: @zerkms - Wonder if you could also help with this. What if I also needed another key/value to be selected as well? In the above example I have the text and text_status.  What if there is also a name I needed to select.  How can I modify your code to do so? Thanks...

Comment: @Rick: change `AND t1.key = 'text'` to `AND t1.key IN ('text', 'text_status')`

Comment: @zerkms - yes i did just that but that returns multiple duplicate of the same user id...i am just looking for user_id,name,text_status,text...and each array being unique...I realize this could be very complex with this type of schema?  Perhaps it would be no-brainer for you but for me its like astrophysics...

Comment: @Rick: hehe. That is why I never use EAV ;-) Well, you got in stuck with your schema ;-) It is a ways to transpose resultset but I cannot remember any simple. Try to google.

Comment: @zerkms - i see..I guess i have to figure this out...must be a reason why Wordpress decided to use this schema. Thanks anyways...

Comment: @zerkms - FYI I searched around and found exactly what I was looking for.  Just wanted to share with you.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3094084/mysql-query-join-data-based-on-two-factors-then-customise-the-way-the-data-is

Comment: @Rick: poor mysql. If I were it I would never execute such a spaghetty ;-)

Comment: @zerkms-unfortunately that will have to due for now until i learn more about how to efficiently query a EAV schema.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've set up your table incorrectly. Make text_status and value exist within the same row.

The way it is right now, you would have to conduct two queries to get to your end result. Where as, the correct way needs only one.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding me.

Comment: Why does text_status have to be a key, instead of just being a column header?

Comment: They already exist in the same row - to get other details related to a particular value (user_id), you have to JOIN/IN/EXISTS.  Text_status isn't a column for the same reason text isn't - the OPs setup supports multiple key/value pairs without impacting columns.

Answer (score 0):

This arbitrary key:value list scheme is alluring because of its flexibility. But it complicates queries obviously. Depending on the structure of your second table you could get away with:

```
SELECT key, value FROM user_table WHERE user_id=123
UNION ALL
SELECT 'email' as key, email as value FROM email_table WHERE user_id=123
```

But that pretty much only returns a list still, not a set of fields.

Answer (score 0):

`key` and `value` looks wrong. SQL already gives you "key" (in the column name) and multiple "values" (in the values given per column in each row).

You've designed your table in a way that contravenes the way Database Management Systems are designed to work, which is leading to your problem. Read about [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).

Ideally your table would look something like this:

```
user_id  text_status   text
------------------------------------------
1        0             this is sample text
2        1             this is sample text
```

Then your query looks like:

```
SELECT `user_id`, `text` FROM `table` WHERE `text_status` = '1';
```

As your table stands now, you'll need something like (untested):

```
SELECT `table`.*
  FROM `table` LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT `user_id`
          FROM `table`
         WHERE `key` = "text_status"
           AND `value` = "1"
       ) AS `_` USING(`user_id`)
 WHERE `table`.`key` = "text"
```

Comment: You're not familiar with [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model), and I suggest you read before making statements.

Comment: Sorry this is not my design - it is Wordpress design...have a look at wp_userdata table...

Comment: @OMGPonies: Is that snippiness? What part didn't I "read"? I am perfectly familiar with EAV (why do you think I'm not? did you find some fake, incorrect version of my resumé somewhere?); SQL is simply not designed for it.

Comment: @Rick: I thought I recognised that travesty. I guess you're stuck with horrible queries then. Note that there are other ways to write the query I showed you, but they all pretty much mean the same thing.

Comment: My comment stands as constructive criticism.  Your statements have always been to normalize for the sake of it - nothing in them suggests you comprehend what EAV has to offer.  I see no reason to give you the benefit of the doubt.  If SQL weren't designed for it, why is EAV a recognized design?  EAV isn't a preferable practice, but choice depends on design/business requirements - not blindly followed dogma.

Comment: @OMGPonies: The fact that the OP has to ask for help with this query, when the non-EAV layout lookup is dead easy, should speak for itself. The OP has neither explained nor demonstrated why he needs EAV, but rather appears to be struggling with it, so in the absence of any other information of course I'm going to recommend a saner, simpler and more logical layout. It's hardly "for the sake of it". Please read yourself before making statements.

Comment: Your comment reinforces what I've already said - when exposed to something you don't comprehend, you default to normalization before you took enough time to understand what was presented to you and why the design choice was made.

Comment: @OMGPonies: Yes, normalization is the best approach. I'm not really sure what your point is aside from trying to flame me, or to paint a picture that I somehow do not know what I'm doing just because you don't share my opinion. In my opinion, EAV is an inferior approach here, and I have not wavered in that opinion once throughout this discourse. I suggest that we agree to disagree, as this is no longer productive.

Comment: No, normalization is not always the answer - there are no absolutes, and I've already listed reasons for why in other comments in this question.  Your entrenchment is not a sign of strength - it does nothing for your point; it only reinforces that you are a slave to dogma and won't think for yourself. You lack design/development experience, and in the face of constructive criticism react poorly.  You have a lot of professional and personal development ahead of you, and I look forward to seeing you improve.

Comment: @OMGPonies: Your flagrant condescension has only demonstrated that I was right to suggest that we end this "discussion". I'm sure you'd never talk to someone like that in real life... at least, I hope not. You have _no clue_ what experience I do/do not have. You're guessing, and guessing wrong. Learning some respect might do you some good. Again, I _did not_ say that it's "always the answer" or that it's an absolute. I'm talking about _this use case_. Feel free to continue ignoring that: you'll be doing it on your own. Cheers.

Comment: You've had the ability to demonstrate your "knowledge", and all you can do is repeat "normalization" verbatim.  Now you want to argue that context matters now, in the face of an established product whose data model can not be changed and one that supports the majority of configuration that a user could envision.  All you do is dig yourself deeper.